# Remove orphaned rados block device

Tags: linux, block-device, ceph

I'm testing ceph at the moment. Today I decided to start over with my cluster and deleted the old one to setup a new one. I forgot to unmap and delete a mapped rbd device from another host. Now I see the following errors in the log and I can't unmap the device:

```
libceph: bad fsid, had ecfaaa06-4bed-43c8-a38b-9566a320fa14 got 3447fbd4-85da-4f80-b545-c9aa0de70cb5
kernel: [6909596.980003] libceph: auth method 'x' error -1
```

Is there any way to remove this device without rebooting the server?